# Why does Hive's DISTRIBUTE BY SORT BY only work if I write it as a sublselect?

Tags: hive

I've confirmed the behavior with both version 0.10 and 0.13.

I have a UDF to which I added [this annotation](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-1994): `@UDFType(stateful = true)`

This works as expected, as in, `MyFun` gets the tuples `(user_id, track_started)` ordered by `track_started ASC`:

```
SELECT
  user_id,
  MyFun(user_id, track_started) AS session_id,
  track_started,
  artist_id,
  artist_name,
  track_id,
  track_name
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      user_id,
      track_started,
      artist_id,
      artist_name,
      track_id,
      track_name
    FROM
      track_listened_tiny
    DISTRIBUTE BY
      user_id
    SORT BY
      track_started    
  ) a
```

However, this doesn't:

```
SELECT
  user_id,
  MyFun(user_id, track_started) AS session_id,
  track_started,
  artist_id,
  artist_name,
  track_id,
  track_name
FROM
  track_listened_tiny
DISTRIBUTE BY
  user_id
SORT BY
  track_started
```

When written in this way, `MyFun` is evaluated in the map state and thus doesn't get the tuples ordered correctly. It seems like this is in contrast of what `@UDFType(stateful = true)` is supposed to do. Is it a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hive generally assumes that UDFs are "stateless" - that is, that it does not matter in which order the records are passed to it. So in your second query, it executes the udf in the map phase, before the sort happens. The fact that it's in descending order is probably just because that's how your data is in the input files.

Your first query forces the sort to happen before the function is applied.

Put "explain" before your query to see the execution plan.

Comment: Thanks that is very convincing. I'll investigate if this is the case. I have had `@UDFType(stateful = true)` (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-1994) on the UDF though. Would that still be an expected behavior?

Comment: It was indeed because the function was evaluated in the Map stage, but that seems to be in contrary of what `@UDFType(stateful = true)` is supposed to do..

Comment: After reading through the jira, you're right, it seems like marking it stateful should cause it to happen in the reducer; it might be a bug if it does not. I think a lot of that type of logic has probably not gotten a lot of attention recently since it's been somewhat superceded by the addition of windowing and analytics functions in version 0.11: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+WindowingAndAnalytics